# Multiple variable list comprehension python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to iterate over multiple object. How can i rewrite it using list comprehension?

```
for character in characters_rs:
    for item in mapping:
        if character.Get('NomId') == item.get('Номенклатура'):
            item['Attributes'] = character.Get('Attributes')
```

I tried something like `aggregated_list = [character for character in characters_rs for item in mapping if character.Get('NomId') == item.get('Номенклатура') ]` , but it's not what i expect.

mapping is a list, characters_rs is a custom RecordSet structure.

Comment: You don't seem to be building a list here, so you shouldn't use a list comprehension at all.

Comment: You cannot have an assignment statement in a list comprehension.

Comment: How is `aggregated_list` related to the first code snippet?

Comment: What type of data are `character.Get('NomId')` and `item.get('Номенклатура')` - are they integers, strings, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap the two loops since they are independent. That makes the process clearer: you want to update some of the `item`s of the `mapping` iterable:

```
for item in mapping:
    for character in characters_rs:
        if character.Get('NomId') == item.get('Номенклатура'):
            item['Attributes'] = character.Get('Attributes')
```

More precisely, you update each `item` with the last `character` having `character.Get('NomId') == item.get('Номенклатура')`. Hence the list/dict comprehension that returns the updated version of `mapping`:

```
[{**{'Attributes': character.Get('Attributes')
     for character in characters_rs
     if character.Get('NomId') == item.get('Номенклатура')},
  **item}
 for item in mapping]
```

Explanation: `{**d1, **d2}` merges two dicts. Here, the first dict contains the last character having `character.Get('NomId') == item.get('Номенклатура')` mapped to `Attributes` (this dict may be empty), and the second is simply `item` itself.